# How to convert class HOC to Functional HOC?

Tags: reactjs

I've implemented a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) `withProvider` with `class` based component :

```
import React from "react"
import Context from "./context"

const WithProvider = Component => {
    class WithContext extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }
        render() {
            return <Context.Provider value={{ type: this.props.type }} >
                <Component {...this.props} />
            </Context.Provider>
        }
    }
    return WithContext
}

export default WithProvider
```

But all the components in the codebase are Functional based.

So, I want to convert `withContext` into [Functional](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A functional form of HOC is as the following:

```
const withFoo = (Component) => {
  return (props) => {
    return <Component foo={'foo!'} {...props} />
  };
}

const Bar = withFoo((props) => {
  return <div>hello: {props.foo} bar: {props.bar}</div>
})
```

You can easily imply this example to your own needs.

Comment: If you have a `useState` hook, where we call it : before the closure or inside it ? I have errors for both of the cases.

Comment: I solved the issue by adding the name of the closure like this : `return Foo=props=>{..}`.